# Android M permission dialogue not appearing in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

I am trying to ask for READ_PHONE_STATE permission for android M but it works in Activities and when i implement it in fragment it doesn't show dialogue box.
Here is the code.

```
if (preference.getToken() == null) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        requestReadPhoneStatePermission();
                    } else {
                        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("appCode", Constants.TRACKING_ID);
                        params.put("phone", tm.getDeviceId());
                        DeviceUserService.getDeviceUser(params, getContext());
                        bookmark();
                    }
```

Here is method `requestReadPhoneStatePermission`

```
public void requestReadPhoneStatePermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }
    }
```

And here is code on onRequestPermissionsResult.

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case READ_PHONE_STATE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
        }
    }
```

What i am missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kindly, Can you post the complete the answer here so it can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the requestReadPhoneStatePermission method wrong.

**EDIT**

I saw this old post get upvoted and realized it was not a correct implementation.

This is the proper way to handle permission requests.

```
public void requestReadPhoneStatePermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, READ_PHONE_STATE);
}



@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(requestCode==READ_PHONE_STATE){
        if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            //do your thing
        }
        else{
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)){
                //user denied the permission but did not check the "never show again" option. 
                //You can ask for the permission again or show a dialog explaining
                //why you need the permission with a button that requests the permission again on click.
            }
            else{
                //user denied the permission and checked the "never show again" option. 
                //Here you can show a dialog explaining the situation and that the user has 
                //to go to the app settings and allow the permission otherwise yor feature 
                //will not be available.
            }
        }
    }

}
```